# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to Category type

Tags: java

i have a combobox.it has category name.so i need to pass string to category.
Category category = (Category)cmbCategory.getSelectedItem(); this line get error saying cant cast string to category type..

```
private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    double amount = Double.parseDouble(txtAmount.getText());
    Expense expense = new Expense();
    expense.setReason(txtReason.getText());
    expense.setAmount(amount);
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy");

    Category category = (Category)cmbCategory.getSelectedItem();
    String startDate = ((JTextField)txtDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();

    try {
        Date date = format.parse(startDate);
        expense.setDate(date);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ExpenseView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    expense.setCategory(category);
    ExpenseController.saveExpense(expense);
}
```

Comment: is the type of `cmbCategory.getSelectedItem();` String?

Comment: yes.i pass it as string

Comment: Well then that is you're problem. You are trying to tell the compiler that `getSelectedItem()` is going to give you a `Category` or subclass of `Category`, which `String` is not.

Comment: You might consider implementing some kind of `Category.forName(String)` method, which returns a `Category` based on the given `String`.

Comment: i need to pass it as category object to model->expense.java class.model->expense.java class has getter which accept category object.i need to pass as object including both valuemember and displaymember (name and id) of combo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to convert and then assign a `String` to a `Category`.

Since `String` is not a `Category` obviously, nor implementing `Category`, you receive this exception.

You can add your `Category` class a string data member such as `categoryName`and then set it as follows :

```
Category category = new Category().setCategoryName(cmbCategory.getSelectedItem());
```

Comment: thanks for help.it occured bcz i was trying to cast an instance of an Object to a type that it is not. now it ok

Comment: glad to hear, accept the answer for the future people looking at this question :)

Comment: i passed category object to comboadditem methode cmbCategory.addItem(category);.error solved.but when i run and looking at combobox it disappear name.i know problem is i passed category object.but category object has name and id.how i can display name in combo.

Comment: Can you provide a working example in Plnkr/JSFiddle? and as long as this post is solved please do open a new post for any further non-related questions

Comment: May I ask why did you took the accept down? as it does answer the question

Answer (score 1):

`Category.getSelectedItem ();` returns a `String`

unless it is assigned to an attribute of your class Category for example name and is of type string

```
category.setName(cmbCategory.getSelectedItem());
```

Comment: thanks for help.it occured bcz i was trying to cast an instance of an Object to a type that it is not. now it ok